# Nativescript error: tns run android - "Cannot find a compatible Android SDK"

Tags: android, angularjs, sdk, nativescript, tns

I followed the whole Getting Started Tutorial for Mac (https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1).

Now I try to get the sample app running. IOS works fine! 
But Android doesn't work: Not on USB-device, either on Genymotion.

Here the error after typing in:
"tns run android"

```
Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/Username/Documents/Development/sample-Groceries/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 1.8.10
Processing node_modules failed. Exception: Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later.
```

I have installed Android SDK 23, as it was written in the tutorial:

```
android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,android-23,build-tools-23.0.3,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-support --all --no-ui
```

How can I fix it? I tried everything...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question I have would be, have you run `tns doctor`?

Be sure you have your ANDROID_HOME set correctly, pointed to your actual sdk install location, without a trailing slash at the end. here is mine as an example:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/sdks/android-sdk-macosx
```

It's also good to have the tools in the path (example snippet):

```
PATH='/sdks/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/sdks/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS'
```

Comment: tns doctor says everything is fine. I've now redone everything (with a patched version) and I have a new problem, but at the same point. I opened up an issue on Github, because I think it's a problem with the repo. You may answer there, if you have any suggestions. https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/issues/151